# My vue.js application resets the theme color when I type in the text input. How to make the theme color stay?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I set `<meta name="theme-color" content="#HEXCOL" />` in index.html and that gives the desired theme color to the browser's tab:

[image: Required Browser Tab Color]

but when I go on and type even a single letter in input, the tab color gets reset:

[image: Browser tab color reset]

How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme color gets reset, because you are inserting data into an input field on a page with `http://` (not using a secure connection). Chrome is resetting the theme color to the default and is adding a warning triangle to the URL so that the user is aware that his or her inputs are not secure. That's a security feature of Chrome. You should try it out with a valid SSL/TLS certificate on HTTPS and then it should stay the same color.